# call a method of a parent view from a view embedded in a UIContainerView. swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

ill try to explain this as best i can.
i have a UIViewController. inside it there is a 'SKIP' button and theres also a UIContainerView. embedded in that container view is a UIPageViewController. the Page View Controller have 4 pages.

i want to be able to make the 'SKIP' button (in the parent UIViewController) to have a different color for each page in the PageViewController.
Example: if page == 1, SKIP.color = white. if page == 2, SKIP.color = blue...

i dont understand the proper way to call a method inside the parent from the child PageViewController.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check out delegates in iOS/ NSNotificationCentre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use delegation pattern or NSNotification.

## Delegation

Set the parentVC as the pageVC's delegate and remember that the parentVC must conform to page view controller's delegate protocol

```
class ParentClass: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
    // ...
    pageInstanceVC.delegate = self
}
```

and then implement its delegate method (this is where you change the button's color), you might want to implement it in 
`- pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers:` or `- pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:` Complete docs can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerDelegateProtocolRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPageViewControllerDelegate/pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers:)

## Notification

Set parentVC to listen to page change notification and implement the required method when the notification is received

```
// Parent VC 
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "changeButtonColor", name: "kPageChangeNotif", object: nil)
}

func changeButtonColor(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo as Dictionary
    let pageNumber = userInfo["PageNumber"]

    // Change the button color
    // .....
}
```

Then sent out notification when page is changed

```
// PageVC
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("kPageChangeNotif", object: nil, userInfo: ["PageNumber" : 2])
```

Remember to remove parentVC from observing NSNotificationCenter's (`removeObserver`) when appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You can use Post Notification to accomplish this,

and you will trigger it when the user changes the page.